# How do I able to store images inside 'src/main/resources/imgs'?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, pom.xml

Iam using Maven and Iam trying to download images into a folder inside `src/main/resources/imgs`

Iam unable to download images inside 'imgs' folder , I tried below ways like:

a) System.getProperty("user.dir")

b) getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("imgs");

c) getClass().getResourceAsStream("imgs")

BUT none of above working for me.

**Please suggest me how do I able to store images inside** `'src/main/resources/imgs'`

Comment: In maven, you shouldn't, they should be stored in the `resources` directory.  When you application is built and deployed, the `src` directory will no longer exist...

Comment: no no, i do not store images directly inside resource folder, instead downloaded images should get into inside folder 'src/main/resources/imgs' directly.. pls understand my query!

Comment: Don't download files into your classpath directories. Choose a different, dedicated, directory for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "download" - Do you understand that `src` won't exist when you application is built and bundled?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Could you please be bit breif? I mean what code to use to store images in another directory?

Comment: No, I won't write the code for you. Read a Java tutorial on IO. Choose a location, write to it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Actually my task is: I need to download some images into some folder and then need to reuplaod it.. So for that I need to store downloaded image into some temporary folder.. If my approach is wrong, pls suggest me someway inorder to achive my task!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Atleast tell me do I need to use ImageIO? and where you want me to keep folder? inside src/main/some-new-folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with maven to be honest. It seems your problematic concerns your application once built, not the dependencies resolving/building/packaging process (which is what maven does).

Comment: No `/src/main/...` are folders that maven conventionally uses to build your application. They have nothing to do with your application code. Choose a completely separate directory (ex `/usr/share/...`). Using `ImageIO` is up to you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Actually i need to download images somewhere inside myapplication, not in my PC whereevr I like..

Answer (score 0):

You should be trying to store images into a location that won't be available at runtime.  The `src` folder won't exist once your application is built and bundled.

You have lots of options available to you...

### You Could...

Create a directory in `user.home` and store the images there, but this does tend to clutter things up...

```
String format = ...
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
String path = home + File.separator + "downloadedImages";
File fPath = new File(fPath);
if (fPath.exists() || fPath.mkdirs()) {
    File imageFile = new File(fPath, "image");
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);
    ImageIO.write(img, format, imageFile);
}
```

### You Could...

Create a temporary file using something like [`createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which will allow to you to write the image out and then read it back it when you need it...

For example...

```
String format = ...;
File tmp = File.createTempFile("name", "img");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...); // Download the image...
ImageIO.write(img, format, tmp); // Write the image to the tmp folder...

// Deal with the image as you need...
```

Comment: All I need is to download images inside my application in some folder, instead of  some other place in my PC.  So, please tell me where is the best place to store? ( mine is Maven application )

Comment: So, you're trying to extract images that are embedded in your application to some external location??