# Not able to store images in application path Spring mvc (java.io.FileNotFoundException)

Tags: spring-mvc

in spring mvc i want to store images into `images folder`  .which is there inside `resources`

i tried with following code

```
BufferedImage image = null;
        byte[] imageByte;

        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(studentDetails.getStuImg());
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();

        String file=    request.getContextPath()+"/resources/images/imageee.png";

        // write the image to a file
        File outputfile = new File(file);  
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
```

but i am getting following Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \campasAdmin\resources\images\imageee.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.spi.FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController.addfeeCategory(StudentController.java:272)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cb2af793.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b76b9e3.addfeeCategory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

how to store into following location

[image: please look at derectory]

i want to in above location.
how to do it, please help me. thank you!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always try to use generic solution because path differs from OS to OS.

use java seperators so that whatever the OS (linux/windows) it works fine always.

```
File.separator (import java.io.File;)
```

OR in your case if OS is **windows** then refer below code.

Try replacing this line :
String file=    request.getContextPath()+"/resources/images/imageee.png";

With this :
String file=    request.getContextPath()+"`\\resources\\images\\imageee.png`";

If you want to store images in tomcat(catalina_home) location then please refer below code.

```
String catalinaRootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
File dir = new File(catalinaRootPath + File.separator + "images");
if (!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

and then write images inside this or you can create sub-directories also and then write.

Comment: will the path is same , means will it store in `images` folder only . even in the production ?

Comment: still same Exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \campasAdmin\resources\images\rama.png (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Comment: Please refer this <https://stackoverflow.com/a/21978365/6572971> answer..thank you

Comment: thank you @Sandeep Rathore . bbut its for local location . what if i deployed project and its in production where do these images have to store ?

Comment: for that you can store images in your tomcat home location..if you need code let me know i will post it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use [Spring Content](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content).  Then you don't need to worry about how implement any of this code and you have much more flexibility over where to store your images.

It is pretty easy to add to your application.

> pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
public class EnableFilesystemStoresConfig {

    @Bean
    File filesystemRoot() {
        try {
            return new File("/path/to/your/images");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {}
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

> ImageStore.java

```
  public interface ImageStore extends Store<String> {
  }
```

That's it.  The ImageStore is essentially a Spring ResourceLoader so all you need to do is auto-wire it to use it.  The `spring-content-fs`  dependency will cause Spring Content to inject a filesystem-based implementation on your behalf:

> ImageStoreTest.java

```
@RunWith(...)
public class ImageStoreTest {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentStore store;

    @Test
    public void sample() {
       InputStream is = getImageStream();
       Resource r = store.getResource("/some-image.jpg");
       OutputStream os = ((WritableResource)r).getOutputStream();
       IOUtils.copy(is, os);
       is.close();
       os.close();
    }

    public InputStream getImageStream() {
       ...
    }
}
```

If you want to store the images in a database instead, or in S3 then all you need to do is change the dependency to the one that you want and update the `@Configuration` to add connection details for that particular type of storage.  Reference guides are at the bottom of [this page](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).

As your using spring web-mvc I assume you have a REST API so you can go one step further.  Add this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

This `@Import` to your StoreConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
@Import(RestConfiguration.class)
public class EnableFilesystemStoresConfig {
```

This `@StoreRestResource` annotation to your ImageStore.

> ImageStore.java

```
  @StoreRestResource(path="images")
  public interface ImageStore extends Store<String> {
  }
```

Now you will have a fully functional (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) REST-based image service at `/images` that will use your ImageStore to store your images in `/path/to/your/images`.

So...

`curl --upload-file example-image.jpg /images/example-image.jpg`

will upload example-image.jpg and store it in `/path/to/your/images/example-image.jpg` on your server then:

`GET /images/example-image.jpg`

will return download it.

HTH

Comment: Let me know if you are using Spring Boot and I can update this answer accordingly

Comment: will you check out my code for storing and retrieving image. there i am getting some exceptions

Comment: pleese check it [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545227/java-nio-file-accessdeniedexception-while-retrieving-image-from-the-system-path]