# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: while retrieving image from the system path

Tags: java, path

I have been storing the image as follows

```
if(imgString != null )
        {  
        BufferedImage image = null;
        byte[] imageByte;

        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imgString);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();

        String realPath  = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/images/"+studentDetails.getFirstname()+".png");

        File outputfile = new File(realPath); 


        ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile); 
        studentDetails.setStuImg(outputfile.toString());

    }
```

and trying to get the image from that location as follows

```
if(imagePath != null)
            {
                    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(imagePath)); // getting exception here

                    encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);

            }
```

please look at my stackTrace

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: 
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Unknown Source)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController.getStudentAdmissionByAdmissionId(StudentController.java:510)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cb2af793.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$537bb5b8.getStudentAdmissionByAdmissionId(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**how would I avoid this exception**  or did I miss any thing .

in some post I have read that we need to release that location, if that location had used previously.

if that is the case how and where should i do so ?.

please help me. thank you !.

Comment: What is value of `imagePath`?

Comment: this is the path `F:\spring\springUdemyWorkpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\campasAdmin\resources\images\chitcku.png`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the similar thing and it seems to be working. Below is my working code.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    BufferedImage bi2 =
            new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    String realPath  = "/Users/xxx/Downloads/image002.png";

    File outputfile = new File(realPath); 


    ImageIO.write(bi2, "png", outputfile); 

    Path filePath = Paths.get("/Users/xxx/Downloads/image002.png");

    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);

    String encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    System.out.println(encodedFile);


}
```

It gave me an output like

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAIAAAD/gAIDAAAANElEQVR42u3BAQ0AAADCoPdPbQ43oAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAfgx1lAABLpXWfAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

It seems like you are using windows, so you can try the following,

- Try creating and reading file from some other location on your machine.
- Try escape character \ in the path like

> F:\spring\springUdemyWorkpace\....

That might help.

- Open the file location in the windows explorer and check file permissions.

That might help.